# Test connection loss in unit tests (in a thrift C++ application or in general)

Tags: c++, unit-testing, tcp, connection, thrift

It's not crazy to assume that my thrift client will just [lose connection without any warning](https://liveramp.com/engineering/reconnecting-thrift-client/). In which case I have to detect that and reconnect to the server.

I have a multithreaded C++ program (both client and server) that use thrift with a lock-free object pool, etc, etc. It's a complicated system with locks and sleeps that needs good testing, and I need to **simulate losing connection** in my unit tests. My tests use loopback (127.0.0.1) to connect to the thrift server. Is there a way to simulate a lost connection to see how my software reacts and test it?

I'm on Linux, Ubuntu 18.04. I don't mind using system calls to trick my tests.

If there's any additional information you need, please ask. I'm not sure if there's more information I can provide.

Comment: Connect through a quick and dirty proxy, and instruct the proxy to randomly tear down the proxied connections.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks. That sounds like a viable idea. Do you know of some proxy software with probably some API access that I can utilize?

Comment: No, this sounds something that's fairly customized and boutique. But it shouldn't take much time to hack together a dumb proxy that listens on a port, forwards all connections and bi-directional traffic to the real server, using a poll() loop, together with having another socket open where it gets commands to close the existing proxy connections. The biggest challenge here is not writing the no-brainer proxy, but the fact that even in this scenario you have some non-deterministic behavior. Just because the proxy close()d a connection and ack-ed this, your app may not yet see a broken socket.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I see. Actually I only detect the broken connection when the client makes a request. So, if I succeed with creating that proxy, I guess I'll make a request, watch it fail, then reconnect, and watch it succeed. That'll probably be sufficient. Thanks for the idea. I'll work on it.

Answer (score 0):

As your question is tagged unit-testing, I will give some remarks related to unit-testing.  What you are currently doing, however, appears to be integration testing.

In unit-testing you focus on testing your code in isolation from depended-on-components.  That is, instead of testing your code together with the thrift library, you would rather use some mock of that library.  Your code should not be able to tell the difference of whether it is working with the real library or with the mocked one.  The mock's behaviour is controlled by the test code.  This gives your test code a large degree of freedom to exercise the various scenarios you are interested in.  If you are interested to learn more about it, search for "mocking", "dependency injection" and "inversion of control", and you will find lots of information.

That said, there is certainly nothing wrong with doing integration tests in combination with the thrift library: Thorough testing of some code will require both unit and integration testing.  It's only that the goals and approaches of the two differ.